# Magento - can't upload product images in admin

Tags: javascript, flash, .htaccess, magento

I have recently upgraded from Magento 1.5 to 1.7.  Since then I can't upload product images.  The 'Browse' and 'Upload' buttons appear, but after reaching 100% it disappears and the image is not added.

The images are being uploaded into the /media/tmp folder, but not into /media/catalog.  Also, I receive the 2 javascript errors:

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined (prototype.js)
2. #media_gallery_content-image-0 .cell-each input (product.js)

The site is also currently under a sub-domain while in development, so the magento installation is not directly under root.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Adding a php.ini file
- Removing htaccess file from media folder
- Giving 777 permission recursively to Media folder
- Disabling recently added extensions
- Using the dull uploader (no flash uploader)
- Using different browsers (IE, Chrome, FF)
- Replacing both prototype.js and product.js with different versions

I've been working on this for a while and I'm starting to bang my head against the wall.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have ssl/https enable? If HTTPS is used to work in the admin, SSL certificate should be valid. Self-signed SSL certificates are not supported ... http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to work on this:
Fix for compatibility with SUPEE-8788
https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78/files#diff-0496ceab82e51dcadccb8a23074fbe17L97

I hope this helps!